# question about probability of drawing two letters

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I was studying about an exam and one question was asking:

From a box containing the letters in the word PROBABILITY two letters are
taken at random. Using the classical definition of probability, compute the
probability of obtaining the letters P and R.

I said that in order to obtain the letter P is 1/11 and for r is 1/10(since we remove an element from the box) and then i multiplied the result so i could get the chance on them happening together.

Although my finl result was 1/110, the answer in the book was 1/55.

Does anyone know if i am mistaken in my logic or the answer is incorrect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is the probability of the first letter you draw being a $P$ and the second letter being an $R$.

You neglected to consider the case of the first letter being drawn as an $R$ and the *second* letter being the $P$.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer correctly computes the probability of drawing P and R *in that order*. To get the correct answer, you also need to account for the probability of drawing R, then P.